# Django server not refreshing pages after reloading

Tags: reactjs, django, server, page-refresh

When I start the Django server it gives me proper output at first but the next time I make changes to code it does not reflect the changes even after reloading. I am usin react at the frontend.

Comment: Try to refresh the page with Ctrl+R or Ctrl+F5.

Comment: If you have `debug=False` then `restart` the server and reload

Comment: Okay, its working fine now but if I face the same issue again I will definitely try this...

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem Couple days ago. Then I found out Putty. Its a program thats connects to server (screean share). Download Putty and login to your account. From Conslore run command. It Should Work (Sorry for Eanglish :/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Its alright, Thank-you !

Comment: @NISARGANDHRAMAN, are you _sure_ this answers your question? You didn't say anything about a remote machine so I'm not sure how PuTTY or advise to log into anything is relevant. PuTTY is _not_ a screen sharing app, and this just says to "run [some unspecified] command".

Comment: @Chris the server works just fine so I didn't use PuTTY. It was my system  issue which is been fixed  if in future  I face such kind of issues I will definitely use this app.

Comment: @NISARGANDHRAMAN, PuTTY has _nothing whatsoever to do with_ the question you asked. Please don't accept answers unless they actually answer your question. Questions and answers here are meant to help future users, and accepting an answer like this leads people down the wrong path.